# jQuery File Upload Plugin in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to use this jQuery File Upload plugin in my CakePHP project:
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
The demo works fine, it also works in my CakePHP project when I place the 'server' folder from the plugin in my CakePHP webroot directory. But this way it uploads the images in webroot/server/php/files. I want to be able to upload the files in webroot/img since that is the directory used by CakePHP for images.

I found the following configuration lines but i don't know how to change this parameters to go few levels up, or start from the webroot. It seems like it depends on where the script file resides, I am really bad with this variables, can anyone help me ?

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) 
{$this->options = array(
'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',            
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/'
```

Comment: Grab the latest copy from https://github.com/inimist/FileUpload if anyone wants it be working with CakePHP 2.x while using latest jQuery plugin at https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change this code in the options.

```
$this->options = array(
'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',            
'upload_dir' => WWW_ROOT.'/img/',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/img/'
```